# API Implementation and Architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server, express.js

I recently put together an Express/Node API that consumes and transforms an additional third party API.

And while everything is working great, I feel there may be ways to improve the architecture and implementation.

This is my current implementation:

```
    nodes_modules/
    routes/
    ...api.js
    ...search.js
   index.js
   .babelrc
   .config.js
   .package.json
```

#### api.js

```
import express from "express";
let router = express.Router();

router.use('/search', require('./search'));

module.exports = router;
```

#### search.js

```
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import transformer from "transformer";
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:type', (req, res) => {

    const type = req.params.type;

    axios.get('http://example.com/api/' + type)
        .then((response) => {

            let transformed = {};

            switch(type) {
                case "people":
                    transformed = transformer.search(response.data, "results[*].{ name: name }");
                    break;
                case "aircrafts":
                    transformed = transformer.search(response.data, "results[*].{ name : aircraftName }");
                    break;
                default:
                    res.status(400).send({ error : "Bad request" });
                    break;
            }

            res.send({original: response.data, transformed: transformed });
        })
        .catch( () => {
            res.status(400).send({ error : "Bad request" });
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({  extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.use('*', (req,res) => {
   res.status(404).send('Page Not Found');
});

app.listen(3030, function() {
   console.log('running on port 3030');
});
```

I appreciate any suggestions for improvement, pointing out of any flaws or useful changes that can be made to the current implementation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After reading over the code snippets you included, it looks pretty simple.

The only concern I have is that if the *switch* statement reaches the *default* case, then `res.status(400).send()` is called , and then just after the *switch* statement, `res.send()` is called... If a `400` status is sent, then it doesn't seem appropriate to send the response data (even though `transformed` wouldn't be assigned in the *default* case.

One other improvement I see is that the `400 Bad Request` response could be made consistent by moving that into a function and calling it in the two places where a `400` response is sent. So in the example below, that is defined as the function `badRequest()` inside the callback to `router.get()`, or that could be moved outside the callback and would then likely need to accept the response object as a parameter.

```
router.get('/:type', (req, res) => {
    function badRequest() {
        res.status(400).send({ error : "Bad API request" });
    }
    const type = req.params.type;

    axios.get('http://example.com/api/' + type)
        .then((response) => {

            let transformed = {};

            switch(type) {
                //..omitting lines for brevity
                default:
                    badRequest();
                    return; //stop the function, since 400 response sent
            }

            res.send({original: response.data, transformed: transformed });
        })
        .catch( () => {
            badRequest();
        });
});
```

Comment: But, your change to the `default:` handler still doesn't prevent it trying to do `res.send()` after you've already done `badRequest()`.  So, it doesn't look like you fixed that part yet.  You could just `return` after calling `badRequest()`, or instead of calling `badRequest()` in the `default:` handler, you could just `throw` and let the `.catch()` call `badRequest()`.

Comment: I was mostly just trying to illustrate the abstraction of the bad request response, without fixing the former issue, but I have updated the snippet to return in the `default:` case. One could also argue that the `default:` case could be removed and if `transformed` is truth (i.e. `<> {}`) then send the JSON object, otherwise call `badRequest()` (or just send that 400 response there)